# Create a worksheet that automatically updates a transposed version of another

Tags: excel, transpose, vba

I am trying to transpose matrix from one Excel sheet into another and have that new Excel matrix automatically updated when the original is changed.
I am trying to make it look like this in the new worksheet:

```
='Table 2'!A1 ='Table 2'!A2 ='Table 2'!A3 ='Table 2'!A4 

='Table 2'!B1 ='Table 2'!B2 ='Table 2'!B3 ='Table 2'!B4 

='Table 2'!C1 ='Table 2'!C1 ='Table 2'!C3 ='Table 2'!C4
```

I tried to make a macro but i cant figure it out.

Comment: Why not using the 'Transpose' function.

Comment: If I try to transpose the formulas, it doesn't actually switch the position of the formulas. It transposes the format, but it for some reason if C55 is in the transposed matrix it will now be ='Table2'!C55 instead of what it should be. I attempted to fix the cells using $ but the outcome was the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use **this formula**:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1;COLUMN()-1; ROW()-1)
```

**Or this Array Formula** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>):

```
= TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A1:Z100)
```

(Change range appropriately)